# Put the shapefile into plot of interp2d XYZ

Tags: python, plot, shapefile

I tried to put the shapefile of my study area into the interpolation map that I have generated as in this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy89H.png), the latitude is bounded from 0 to 14, while longitude from 95 to 126.

I already import the shp file as in this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk2Xe.png), but i want it only from the same latitude and longitude of the generated map and plot it into the generated map as one of the layer.

Here is the code

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('worldregions.shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
f = interp2d(Lon, Lat, SSS, kind="linear")
x_coords = np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1)
y_coords = np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1)
Z = f(x_coords, y_coords)

fig = plt.imshow(Z,
       extent=[min(y), max(y), min(x), max(x)],
       origin="lower", interpolation='spline36', cmap='jet')

# Show the positions of the sample points, just to have some reference
#fig.axes.set_autoscale_on(False)
plt.scatter(y, x, s=0, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
plt.xlabel('Longitude (N)')
plt.ylabel('Latitude (E)')
plt.title('Sea Surface Salinity (SSS) for January 2015')
clb=plt.colorbar(fig)
clb.ax.set_title('PSU')
plt.gdf()
plt.show()
```

However, there is an error and the shapefile is not layered into the generated map. Here is the error.

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11876\2655980396.py in <module>
     18 clb=plt.colorbar(fig)
     19 clb.ax.set_title('PSU')
---> 20 plt.gdf()
     21 plt.show()

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'gdf'
```

Comment: i guess you want to use `gdf.plot()` instead of `plt.gdf()`